# Question of the subdomain

Tags: subdomains, domain

Our small company is making a website using Wordpress free version. We had used wordpress in the past and would like to continue using it but our subdomain reads www.(ourname)blog.wordpress.com. Our website is not a blog and it would look bit more professional if the blog part is removed. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Thank You!

Comment: WordPress.com is its very own environment with its own [forums](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/) and [support](https://en.support.wordpress.com/). Even then, your URL won't be looking professional unless you have your very own domain (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

You need install wordpress in your own domain. If you use the Wordpress portal, all of sites be accessed this way. You can install on Go Daddy or something similar.

You need buy a domain to install WordPress. After you buy your domain (can be yourcompany.com, for example) you must install WordPress in your domain and will appear in correct form.  Go Daddy has a Wordpress-ready solution. I hope this has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Buying a domain is the first step. But you also need a place for the domain to 'live'. Lots of hosting places that will host your domain for a monthly/yearly fee. Most larger hosts also have an automatic WP installation 'wizard'.

If your company has their own servers, then you could set up a server to host your WP installation. That requires technical competence to ensure proper configuration and security. Without your own servers, you'll need a hosting place for your site.